# Native crash at /system/lib/libskia.so on some Sumsung Android 5.x device

Tags: android

Recently I have got some crash report of my app. It seemed that it's only happened on some Samsung Android 5.x devices. Currently we have got samsung/a5ltezt and samsung/tbltezt on the error list. While it's all OK when those devices running Android 4.x system.

Below is the crash log:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a5ltezt/a5ltezt:5.0.2/LRX22G/A500YZZTU1BOK2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 15001, tid: 15034, name: Thread-3294  >>> com.tecom.sip <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb0cb2c38
    r0 b90eb578  r1 b0cb2c58  r2 0000000c  r3 b5a7d363
    r4 0000000c  r5 b90eb578  r6 b0cf2cac  r7 b0cf2c58
    r8 00000000  r9 b0cf2c64  sl 0000000c  fp b0cb2c58
    ip 00000050  sp b0cb2c50  lr b5ac4f5b  pc b5a7d362  cpsr 600f0030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00155362  /system/lib/libskia.so (FrontBufferedStream::readDirectlyFromStream(char*, unsigned int)+41)
    #01 pc e1520001  <unknown>
```

Really thanks if someone shows me a clue.

Comment: Are sure this problem cause of architecture of processsor? Maybe you should add some .so libraries? Also it could be cause of art and dalvik? As i know the difference between 4.x to 5.x is compilation. Here is some reference https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/

Comment: Well, there are over 1K users use this app currently, over 29% of them runs Android 5.0/5.1/6.0, only those two sumsung devices have this problem, really odd.

Comment: Is it the same as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58515